# Differentiation through the integral sign, more general case

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, banach-spaces, book-recommendation, online-resources

I wondered in which cases, given a measurable space $(A,\mu)$, Banach spaces $E,F$, an open $U\subseteq E$ and $f:A\times U\rightarrow F$, we can conclude that the function $s\mapsto\int_A f(x,y)dx$ is smooth on $U$.  (Obviously we need some smoothness and integrability assumptions on $f$ but I couldn't figure out exactly which.  Possibly $A$ should also be assumed a topological space.)

Another thing which came to my mind is that I don't know if it is enough for proving continuous differentiability of a function between Banach spaces to prove the existence and continuity of all directional derivatives (as it is the case in finite dimensional spaces).

Also I would be happy about all recommendations of books / online resources that deal with differentiation in Banach spaces, thanks!

Comment: It is not enough to prove existence + continuity of all directional derivatives. To see this, consider any **unbounded** functional $\varphi : B \to \Bbb{R}$. Furthermore, you do **not** need $A$ to be a topological space, an abstract measure space will suffice. Finally, would a (Banach space adapted) version of this result (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) meet your criteria? It is hard to find a "most general" version :)

Comment: First, thanks a lot for the hint to unbounded functionals!  Second, I have no definite criteria for 'most general' to meet, I just changed the title to 'more general'.  A Banach space adaptet version of the Wikipedia theorem would be nice, my aim is just getting myself used to think in more abstract terms like Banach spaces, measure spaces, etc. and for this reason I think about different settings for some theorems that seem important to me, that's all :)

Comment: By the way, if you are interested in doing things in the more general (Banach-space valued, ...) way, a **really** nice book is Serge Lang's "Real and Functional Analysis" (cf. http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0897-6). I like that book quite a lot although in general I am not too fond of Serge Lang's (more algebraic) books.